# showing record if amount is not paid or not fully paid

Tags: mysql

I am trying following query to get the data

Tables are

1 bill details to store bill details

```
bill_details(bill_no,invoice_no,invoice_date,total,cid)
```

2. bill paid details to store paid amount for bills it can zero or more entry for payment of bills

   ```
    bill_paid_details(id,bill_no,amount,payment_mode)
   ```
3. detail of customer

   ```
   customer_mapping(id,fname,lname,cid)
   ```

I want to show records if amount is not paid or not fully paid.

if amount is not paid means then there is no entry in bill_paid_details

I am trying following query.

```
select bd.invoice_no,bd.invoice_no, bd.total,sum(bpd.amount), cm.fname
from bill_details as bd
left join customer_mapping as cm
on bd.cid=cm.cid
left join bill_paid_details as bpd
on bpd.bill_no=bd.bill_no
group by bd.invoice_no
HAVING bd.total>sum(bpd.amount)
order by bd.invoice_dt
```

This query is executing but not showing any record.

Comment: customer and customer_mapping would normally be separate tables

Comment: Add sample data and expected result.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52ab3/4

Answer (score 1):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT BD.invoice_dt
      ,BD.invoice_no
      ,BD.total
      ,BPD.AMT
      ,C.FNAME
FROM `bill_details` BD
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bill_no, SUM(AMOUNT) AMT
           FROM `bill_paid_details`
           GROUP BY bill_no) BPD ON BD.bill_no = BPD.bill_no
JOIN client C ON C.id = BD.cid
WHERE BD.total <> BPD.AMT
OR BPD.bill_no IS NULL
ORDER BY invoice_dt;
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52ab3/19)

Comment: one invoice can have more that one amount in bpd table so I have to check for sum of all bpd.amount

Comment: @xrcwrn, Try now.